# How to choose a compiler version in Automake?

Tags: configure, autoconf, automake

I have several compilers with the same name but of different versions or location.
The `./configure` script seems to stop at the first it finds in `PATH`. How can I tell Automake to choose one of them according to a custom rule ? I already have a macro which can check the compiler version.

I would like to avoid setting the path by hand (with the `FC` variable) as it can be cumbersome to type each time the whole path.

In my case, several MPI wrapper compilers are located in different directories with the same name (and added to the `PATH` by the user).

The idea would be to use something like `./configure --with-intel` to find and select the IntelMPI compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution : copy the search strategy of `configure` in a macro, with a custom matching criterion. Parsing `PATH` is done by setting the `IFS` variable (which is already defined in configure). In Bash, finding all the executables would be something like :

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=":"
exe="mpif90"
for dir in $PATH
do
   if test -f "$dir/$exe"; then
     custom_test($dir/$exe)
   fi
done
```

**Note:** This is recommanded in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Generic-Programs.html)

> If you need to check the behavior of a program as well as find out whether it is present, you have to write your own test for it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to set up `CC` and other "precious" variables via a shell script, lots of them for cross compilation.  So I have a bunch of shell scripts sitting around with contents like:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux
export CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}-gcc
...
PATH=$PATH:/some/arm/compiler/bin:/some/arm/compiler/usr/bin # for arm compiler tools
export CFLAGS="..."
```

to set up the `configure` configuration. So at configure time I do:

```
source /path/to/configuration/some-arm-compiler.sh
./configure ...
```

It saves a lot of typing.

EDIT: So it could work for your particular case something like:

**mpi-a.sh**

```
export FC=mpif90
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/mpi-a/bin:/path/to/mpi-a/usr/bin
```

**mpi-b.sh**

```
export FC=mpif90
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/mpi-b/bin:/path/to/mpi-b/usr/bin
```

So for compiling with one of them:

```
source /path/to/mpi-a.sh
./configure ...
```

and the other:

```
source /path/to/mpi-b.sh
./configure ...
```

Comment: What if you have several compilers with the same name but on different locations ?

Comment: Make sure that `PATH` set up in the script is set up correctly to only find the one that's needed. This seems to be something that you're doing already.

Comment: I have taken the opposite approach : all possible paths must be appended to PATH by the user and `configure` chooses one of them according to its options. Your approach is interesting (and surely more in the UNIX spirit than mine) but you must have as many scripts as there are compilers. Also these scripts are machine-dependent, therefore not portable.

Comment: Rather than sourcing a file, it is often simpler to put the commands in a `config.site`.  eg, rename `some-arm-compiler.sh` `/some/path/config.site` and it will be automatically sourced by `configure` when prefix is set to `/some/path`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, Thanks for that info. I didn't know about that feature. I think the `CONFIG_SITE` method of doing the same thing might work out better for me.  I'll have to think about it...